# How to Set Image Encoding on pylon camera

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the pylon_camera ROS package for my Basler acA2040-90uc camera. I was following installation procedures for the driver, and when I run the line:

> roslaunch pylon_camera pylon_camera_node.launch

I see some camera info such as name and exposure time in the Terminal but then the errors:

> [ WARN] [1496427607.046367698]: No image encoding provided. Will use 'mono8' or 'rgb8' as fallback!
> [ERROR] [1496427607.060515363]: Couldn't find a fallback solution!
> [ERROR] [1496427607.061636139]: Error while start grabbing

In the log file generated, I see the warning

> WARN [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/pylon_camera/include/pylon_camera/internal/impl/pylon_camera_base.hpp:442(PylonCameraImpl::setImageEncoding) [topics: /rosout, /pylon_camera_node/image_raw, /pylon_camera_node/camera_info] No image encoding provided. Will use 'mono8' or 'rgb8' as fallback!

I know this camera can support the encoding 'bayer_bggr8', so it is supported. I can also view the images on the Pylon viewer app on a different machine (this one doesn't support that app).

It seems that they may be a service I can call to manually set this image encoding? I was unable to find any information about it, so any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263085/how-to-set-image-encoding-on-pylon-camera/) by [Omkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30582/omkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The encoding can be set with a rosparam and is normally read from a yaml file that also contains other parameters like exposure. The default is [here](https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera/blob/indigo-devel/config/default.yaml). Setting the image_encoding (line 20) to 'bayer_bggr8' should work.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Omkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30582/omkar/) on 2017-06-05**:
Thanks for helping! This did the trick!
Using the rosparam command works. Alternatively, one can just uncomment line 20 in the file and change it to bayer_bggr8.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-06-06**:
No problem. It's always nice to see that people are using our driver.

**Comment by [pedro_bb72](https://answers.ros.org/users/39704/pedro_bb72/) on 2019-03-12**:
Hi I changed however it is not updated and keep saying I didn't specified it. What do you have to do after changing parameters? Thanks

**Comment by [IvanTomic](https://answers.ros.org/users/56231/ivantomic/) on 2020-07-27**:
Hi, pedro_bb72 I think you shoud rebuild pylon_camera package.